# Batch script not able to access remote drive when scheduled

Tags: file, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have a simple batch script that copies files locally from a Sharepoint drive that's mapped on the local machine. This runs just fine when being manually run, but when run using task scheduler, it seems as though the script cannot access the drive at all. Even a simple DIR print out fails. It's also worth noting that the user set to run the script in scheduler has full rights to everything involved and is the same account being used to run it manually.

A couple of the settings for the scheduled task:

- set to run whether user is logged in or not
- running with highest privileges

Any idea how I could get this working in scheduler?

**Edit:**
Screen shots of the scripts and the task run history
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jM7V5.jpg

**EDIT 2**

callCopyFiles.bat

```
del "C:\apache\htdocs\IESite\Reports\*.*?"
FOR /f "delims=" %%L in (directorylist.txt) do (
    echo %%L >> log.txt
    CALL copyfiles.bat "%%L"
)
```

copyfiles.bat

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('DIR %1 /s /b /O:-D') DO (
    COPY "%%I" "C:\apache\htdocs\IESite\Reports"
    goto :end
)
:ender
```

Comment: Are you sure the scheduled batch file is actually running and failing, as opposed to not running at all? Have you tried adding some logging statements to the batch? Can you show us the contents of the batch?

Comment: Just added screen shots of the results and the scripts. I have tried adding logging and what i found was that the loop in the copyfiles script is not looping through because it is unable to access the drive to fetch the list of files to loop through.

Comment: I added your code from your image to your question as text. Next time, please do it this way...it makes it easier for people to help you.  :)

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that this line in callCopyFiles.bat:

```
CALL copyfiles.bat "%%L"
```

is failing because the current directory is different when your batch file is running as a scheduled task.

Try changing this line to list the full path...something like:

```
CALL C:\YourFolderHere\copyfiles.bat "%%L"
```

**EDIT**

Based on the comments, I think you likely need to map the `Z:` drive within the `copyfiles.bat` file.

**EDIT 2**

Don't specify the credentials when mapping the drive.

Just add `NET USE Z: \\YourServer\ShareName` to the `copyfiles.bat` file.

Comment: I put in the full path, but after seeing that it is still not running I added in some log statements to copyfiles.bat. One before the loop, and one inside. Only the first log is being printed telling me that the file is being called, but the loop is not being iterated through at all.

Comment: Try putting a `echo %1` right before the loop in `copyfiles.bat`. What does that show you?

Comment: The proper file path is being printed just as expected. It's the same output as when I run it manually.

Comment: What is the value of `%1`? Does it contain spaces? What if you just run the `DIR %1 /s /b /O:-D` command? What does it display?

Comment: One of the values is "Z:\equipLayout\SPTL\ATL Reports (UEMS II)\*ATL_REPORT*.*". They do contain spaces. When I print out that DIR, nothing printed out when the script was scheduled, yet when run manually then it will print out the contents like it should.

Comment: I'm guessing `Z:` is a network drive? You will most likely need to map it within your `copyfiles.bat` file.

Comment: Yup it is a network drive, which like everything else is fully accessible when running this by hand. I tried throwing in a net use but was getting an error saying "Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed"

Comment: Not when scheduled, no.

Comment: Within `copyfiles.bat`, try mapping `Z:` to `\\ServerIP\Sharename` instead of `\\ServerName\Sharename`. I believe the computer will treat this as if it is connecting to a different server.

Comment: Tried replacing the server name with the IP, but it doesn't seem to notice the connection when I do that, even in windows explorer.

Comment: Can you run the scheduled job with different user credentials? It will need access to your network share and you'll need to map the `Z:` within the batch file.

Comment: Fixed it thanks so much! What ended up working was mapping the drive inside the script like you said, but with using default credentials. Feel free to edit your answer to this and I could mark it as the best.

Comment: What do you mean by "default credentials"? Do you mean just mapping the drive without specifying credentials?

Comment: Yea, just put net use x: \\servername\folder